# When Organized by Conversation, Mail's Inbox sometimes sends out to wrong recipient

Tags: macos, mail.app

When Lion's Mail Inbox is set to "Organize by Conversation", an odd behavior often occurs. If I hit Reply to the latest email from my correspondent, the recipient in the new email is me, not this correspondent.

I'm aware that any of the emails in the Conversation can be individually highlighted (seen as a blue line around that email), and that if this blue line is around one of the correspondent's emails, hitting Reply definitely sets the new email to be sent to this correspondent. However, if nothing is blue-highlighted, and I hit Reply, the new email is set to be sent to... me. Which of course isn't the objective.

Whew, that was harder to explain than the issue, but I hope my question is clear!

Answer (score 1):

There are at least half a dozen threads on [Apple Support](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3284520?start=0&tstart=0) about this, and was a bug that has been fixed as of 10.7.2.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed in 10.7.2. In fact, it now appears that Mail additionally "does the right thing" by addressing a "reply" to one of your own messages to the others on the thread (and not to you).

Comment: Yaaaaay. I'm finding it fixed in 10.7.2 as well. Thanks for pointing this out, raxacoricofallapatorius.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect status as of 10.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

when the individual message is highlighted (as you said the blue box around that message), move the mouse to the separator line between the header and the message body, there is a float toolbar appear, hit the reply button there.

[image: the floating reply/reply all toolbar]

Meanwhile, Mail.app will organize all related message in the Conversation mode (as set in the preference), so the message you sent out (in the Sent box) will appear in the conversation.  So, if the message you sent is the 1st message in the conversation, when you hit reply without any message highlighted, Mail.app will set sent to.... you.

[image: Conversation setting to include all related message]

Comment: Thank you, kukoo. I was aware of the things you pointed out. But I still find that the right behavior is not always working. I've tested this repeatedly, and sometimes the message still gets addressed to me. The top message is from the other person, the top message is highlighted blue, yet still Command-R (or hitting the Reply button) brings up a message that is addressed to me.

Comment: I and ALL my correspondents and colleagues who use Lion have the same problem. And it happens even if the _only_ message in the message list panel is from someone else and even if that message is first in the list of "related" messages.